# Tensorflow - Step-by-step debugging c++ code

Tags: python, tensorflow, debugging, pycharm

I just wanted to check what options I have to do a step-by-step debugging of the C++ TensorFlow code? I do the dev work using PyCharm and in order to do a line-by-line debug a C++ file (say [batch_dataset_op.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/data/batch_dataset_op.cc)), what could I do? One option is to do a custom build of TensorFlow with my print statements... Not sure if there is a smarter way to go about it